# Search for a specific phrase in multiple webpages represented by a variable in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I have a dataset that has a 'url' variable that lead to news articles about the topic I'm researching on. I would like to create a dummy variable which takes the value of 1 if the articles represented by the url contains a specific phrase that I'm interested in, otherwise the dummy variable would be zero.

For example, the current dataframe (df) looks like this:

```
n     url 
1     <www.url-a.com>
2     <www.url-b.com>
3     <www.url-c.com>
```

I am looking for the phrase "climate change" in each of the news articles represented by the url variable. I need R to visit each url, scrape through it, search for the phrase "climate change", and return a value of 1 for the dummy variable if the webpage contains that phrase. For example, if only the news article represented by the second row <www.url-b.com> contains the phrase "climate change", the new "climatedummy" variable would look like:

```
n     url                climatedummy
1     <www.url-a.com>         0
2     <www.url-b.com>         1
3     <www.url-c.com>         0
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
library(rvest)

df$climatedummy <- sapply(df$url, function(x) {
       tryCatch(as.integer(grepl('climate change', html_text(read_html(x)))), 
       function(e) return(NA))
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much! 

When I do this, I get an error message that says:

"Error in open.connection(x, "rb"): HTTP error 404"

I'm guessing this is because some of the urls are invalid. Is there a way to do this while ignoring the bad urls?

Comment: Can't really help you on this because I don't know what URLs you are trying to scrape.

Comment: Is there a way to do this while ignoring the bad/invalid urls? (ie, if there is some problem with the url, ignore it and move to the next one)

Comment: You can use `tryCatch`. See updated answer which might help.